# force swagger to ask for basic http authentication with springfox

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have web service that secure with spring security with basic http authentication.
when i was document it with swagger using springfox-swagger2 library
how can i force  swagger ui to ask for user name password

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why do you want to do that?
If you don't want to expose certain api's in swagger, use a PathSelector. If you don't want everyone to see your Api's, host your swagger ui on a specific server and share the details as per need. Not sure why you would want to add a http authentication.